# Show progress while loading WebViews inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview, android-view

In my android activity I am using a `RecyclerView` which contains number of `MathViews`. `MathView` is a third-party library which shows LaTeX contents (This 
is somewhat similar to `WebView`. Implementation of `MathView` can be seen on this android project. [github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex](https://github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex)).

The problem is, for rendering the content of this `MathView`, it takes a little bit longer time. As I have used few `MathView` components inside a `RecycleView` and the rendering time increases more. Therefore when the Activity started, at first in the view, some white space are shown for few seconds and then the relevant content is rendered.

As a solution for this problem, I need to show a progress bar until all the layout content of the Activity is completely rendered and after rendering is completed show up the Activity.

The relavent source codes are shown below.

MathView;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/equation_item"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <katex.hourglass.in.mathlib.MathView
            android:id="@+id/math_view"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            app:setClickable="true"
            app:setTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:setTextSize="10sp"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <include layout="@layout/item_divider"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Recycler View;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.a37moons.mathcheatsheets.ContentActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_equations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

ViewHolder Class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public MathView mathView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mathView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.math_view);

    }
}
```

Recycler Adapter Class

```
   public class RecyclerAdapterEquations extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

    private List<Equation> equations;
    View view;

    public RecyclerAdapterEquations(List<Equation> equations){
        this.equations = equations;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.equation_view_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Equation sampleEquation = equations.get(position);
        holder.mathView.setDisplayText(sampleEquation.equationString);
       // holder.mathView2.setText(sampleEquation.equationString);
        Log.d("MATH_APP","position "+position+" mathview text set ");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return equations.size();
    }
}
```

Finally the implementation.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapterEquations(sample));
```

Comment: Well if you have complex views and layout that is expected. I'm not sure the delay is caused by the system if you are really using RecyclerView as it's supposed to unless it's running in a very, very low hardware profile. Sounds like the issue might be how you obtain the data to populate the RV

Comment: The project you refer to is in JavaScript. Are you developing in React Native or something similar?

Comment: Unless you update the question with your actual code it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I can see from your code the implementation of RecyclerView is all right.  In the bindView() method, you aren't doing any costly operation. Your Adapter is plain and simple. It has to do with the rendering of  the item of MathView in each recyclerView item. To be sure about that you can replace you your MathView with some simple TextView and see the behavior. If the behavior looks OK, you need to go through the library again to check why it is behaving slowly.

Comment: @AshikeeAbHi If we use TextView it behaves in normal way and render without any delay. But the MathView itself take some time to render its content. Its the normal behavior of MathView.

Comment: I don't need a solution for the speed of the rendering problem. I just need a solution to show a progress bar until all the layout content of the Activity is completely rendered and then after rendering is completed, show up the Activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the answer of written by [azizbekian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674926/5932611), I found the answer to my question.

As mentioned in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674926/5932611), this is the procedure;

> 1. Introduce a [`ProgressBar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674926/5932611) or something similar inside xml file. This view should be declared after `RecyclerView` in order to be
>      drawn on top of `RecyclerView`
> 2. Make `RecyclerView` invisible (via `android:visibility="invisible"`)
> 3. Now `RecyclerView` will be actually laid out **but** not shown on the screen. You need a callback, that would be executed some time
>      later when `RecyclerView` is already setup. Within this callback you
>      will hide progress bar and change visibility of `RecyclerView` to
>      `View.VISIBLE`.

Now as the [`katex.hourglass.in.mathlib.MathView`](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex@master/-/blob/katexmathview/src/main/java/katex/hourglass/in/mathlib/MathView.java#L18) is a subclass of android `WebView`, we can set a `WebChromeClient` to this. Then, we can get the percentage of progress of loading the content.

```
 int loadedPercentage = 0;
 boolean loaded = false;
 mathView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
         super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
         loadedPercentage = newProgress;
         if(newProgress==100) {
             //When the loading is 100% completed; todo
             loaded = true;
             Toast.makeText(getContext(), newProgress + "LOADED COMPLETELY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
 });
```

We can implement a progress bar to show the `loadedPercentage`. When the `loadedPercentage` is 100, we can see the relavent content is completely loaded.
So I editted the `MathView` class as follows;

```
public class MyMathView extends WebView {
    private String TAG = "KhanAcademyKatexView";
    private static final float default_text_size = 18;
    private String display_text;
    private int text_color;
    private int text_size;
    private boolean clickable = false;

    private boolean loaded = false;
    private int loadedPercentage = 0;

    public MyMathView(Context context) {
        //...
    }

    public MyMathView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        //...
    }

    public boolean isLoaded(){
        return loaded;
    }

    public int getLoadedPercentage() {
        return loadedPercentage;
    }

    public void setViewBackgroundColor(int color)
    {
        //...
    }

    private void pixelSizeConversion(float dimension) {
        //...
    }

    private void configurationSettingWebView()
    {
        //...
    }


    public void setDisplayText(String formula_text) {
        this.display_text = formula_text;
        loadData();
    }

   private String getOfflineKatexConfig()
    {
        String offline_config = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html>\n" +
                "    <head>\n" +
                "        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
                "        <title>Auto-render test</title>\n" +
                "        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/katex/katex.min.css\">\n" +
                "        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/themes/style.css\">\n" +
                "        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"file:///android_asset/katex/katex.min.js\"></script>\n" +
                "        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"file:///android_asset/katex/contrib/auto-render.min.js\"></script>\n" +
                " <style type='text/css'>"+
                "body {"+
                "margin: 0px;"+
                "padding: 0px;"+
                "font-size:" +this.text_size+"px;"+
                "color:"+getHexColor(this.text_color)+";"+
                " }"+
                " </style>"+
                "    </head>\n" +
                "    <body>\n" +
                "        {formula}\n" +
                "        <script>\n" +
                "          renderMathInElement(\n" +
                "              document.body\n" +
                "          );\n" +
                "        </script>\n" +
                "    </body>\n" +
                "</html>";
        String start = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /><style> body {"+
       " white-space: nowrap;}</style></head><body>";

        String end = "</body></html>";

        //return   start+offline_config.replace("{formula}",this.display_text)+end;
        return offline_config.replace("{formula}",this.display_text);

    }


    private void loadData()
    {
        if (this.display_text!=null)
        {
            loadedPercentage = 0;
            loaded = false;

            this.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                    loadedPercentage = newProgress;
                    if(newProgress==100) {
                        loaded = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), newProgress + "LOADED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            this.loadDataWithBaseURL("null",getOfflineKatexConfig(),"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
        }
    }


    public void setTextSize(int size)
    {
       //...
    }
    public void setTextColor(int color)
    {
       //...
    }
    private String getHexColor(int intColor)
    {
       //...
    }


    private void setDefaultTextColor(Context context) {
       //...
    }

    private void setDefaultTextSize() {
        //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see the question itself in the description, thus I will refer to [your statement in comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594338/showing-up-android-activity-after-completely-rendering-the-layout#comment86336727_49594338):

> I just need a solution to show a progress bar until all the layout content of the `Activity` is completely rendered and then after rendering is completed, show up the `Activity`.

1. Introduce a [`ProgressBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) or something similar inside xml file. This view should be declared after `RecyclerView` in order to be drawn on top of `RecyclerView`
2. Make `RecyclerView` invisible (via `android:visibility="invisible"`)
3. Now `RecyclerView` will be actually laid out **but** not shown on the screen. You need a callback, that would be executed some time later when `RecyclerView` is already setup. Within this callback you will hide progress bar and change visibility of `RecyclerView` to `View.VISIBLE`.

The problem boils to attaching *"children of `RecyclerView` are initialized"* listener.

As long as [`katex.hourglass.in.mathlib.MathView`](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex@master/-/blob/katexmathview/src/main/java/katex/hourglass/in/mathlib/MathView.java#L18) is a subclass of [`android.webkit.WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)), that means, that in order to get notified about load finished event you should register `WebViewClient` in following approach:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Equation sampleEquation = equations.get(position);
        holder.mathView.setDisplayText(sampleEquation.equationString);
        holder.mathView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // No longer interested in upcoming events - unregister
                view.setWebViewClient(null);
                // Now data is loaded, can make RecyclerView visible
            }
        });
        ...
    }
```

Note, this will make `RecyclerView` to be shown as soon as any of the `MathView`s is loaded. You can wait all of them to be loaded depending on your requirement.

Comment: It seems like you have understood my question. But I tried your solution; It doesn't solve my problem. Can you please further explain the answer.

Comment: I think it's better to share your code instead, as long as I've already shared the concept. Not sure what extra I can add.

Comment: This method is works fine when I loaded a URL to the MathView. But here it is not working.

Comment: What are you loading then? What is `sampleEquation.equationString` and what is the final look of the layout (screenshot maybe?)?

Comment: Thank you for your path. I tried with it and found that registering a `WebChromeClient` solves that problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't call

```
setContentView(layout);
```

as usual, load data in adapter first, thn call

```
setContentView(layout);
```

After that set adapter to recyclerview .